# Displaying matplotlib inside Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have matplotlib script that reads an Excel file and draws it. (as MATPLOT)

And i made another python script looks like a normal program (topmenu, statusbar..) (as GUI)

I want to display MATPLOT in my GUI. Is there any way to call all of the script inside the MATPLOT to run in GUI? Like embedding a video to another website.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

#MENU
topMenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=topMenu)

loadMenu = Menu(topMenu, tearoff=0)
topMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=loadMenu)
loadMenu.add_command(label="Import New", command=doNothing)
loadMenu.add_command(label="Show 'Filter' Menu" , command=showOptions)
loadMenu.add_separator()
loadMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

#GRAPH
#

#StatusBar
status = Label(root, text="File Name:", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7):

### How to embed a matplotlib Figure in a tkinter Frame

The approach presented subclasses `tk.Frame` and `matplotlib.figure.Figure` to make it easy to re-use the code for other purposes.

It creates a `tkFrame`, with all the boilerplate ready to accept and display a matplotlib `Figure`.
It then creates a `Figure` (again, ready to be modified and expanded), and embeds it in the `tk.Frame` created above.
Last, it launches the `tk.mainloop`

```
import matplotlib
import tkinter as tk

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
# from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class GraphPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page Example")
        self.title_label.pack()
        self.pack()

    def add_mpl_figure(self, fig):
        self.mpl_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        self.mpl_canvas.show()
        self.mpl_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.mpl_canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.mpl_canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


class MPLGraph(Figure):

    def __init__(self):
        Figure.__init__(self, figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.plot = self.add_subplot(111)
        self.plot.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 6])


fig = MPLGraph()

root = tk.Tk()
graph_page = GraphPage(root)
graph_page.add_mpl_figure(fig)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: matplotlib Figure embedded in tkinter Frame]

Comment: I know that I can draw lines and create charts. But I want it to be able to read the changes in an Excel file. So if i change the Excel file -or import one from another place if i can do- the gui side will also change. The next thing i want to add is a filter menu that i can select which name to display. (for example: two person and their statistics about how many KM they run each year.)

Comment: Surely, this is not the question you asked above, which is:  "Is there any way to call all of the script inside the MATPLOT to run in GUI? Like embedding a video to another website"

Comment: I think that maybe, you want to ask a *new, more specific question*, that explains precisely what behavior you would like to have, and describe the output you want. You'll probably get a better response if you post the code for your `MATPLOT ` script.

Comment: Just a little change: use **`NavigationToolbar2Tk`** instead of `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`. For details: [What to use instead of NavigationToolbar2TkAgg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50337997/4906053)